# Different ways to return pointers

Tags: go

There's this (admittedly contrived) [exercise](https://exercism.org/tracks/go/exercises/election-day/) to create a function that accepts the number of votes and returns a pointer initialized with the given number of votes. The usage example looks like this:

```golang
var initialVotes int
initialVotes = 2

var counter *int
counter = NewVoteCounter(initialVotes)
*counter == initialVotes // true
```

And one of the solutions (A) is:

```golang
func NewVoteCounter(initialVotes int) *int {
    counter := initialVotes
    return &counter
}
```

But I've seen also another one (B) that passes for the example:

```golang
func NewVoteCounter(initialVotes int) *int {
    return &initialValue
}
```

My question is: those two versions are not equivalent, are they?
(A) initializes new space in memory, copies the passed value and returns pointer to that values.
(B) on the other hand just returns the pointer to the passed value.

Do I get it right, or is there more to it? Is there a "more idiomatic" way to do that in go?

---

For more context, there's a test for that exercise that also passes for both solutions because it only checks the value, but not that the pointer is different. I'm going to attach it for reference, but it's besides the point (which is understanding how pointers work in go)

```golang
func TestNewVoteCounter(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        name  string
        votes int
    }{
        {
            name:  "Simple vote counter with 2 votes",
            votes: 2,
        },
    }

    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            got := NewVoteCounter(tt.votes)
            if got == nil {
                t.Errorf("NewVoteCounter(%d) = %s, &%d", tt.votes, intPtrRepresentation(got), tt.votes)
            }
            if got != nil && *got != tt.votes {
                t.Errorf("NewVoteCounter(%d) = %s, &%d", tt.votes, intPtrRepresentation(got), tt.votes)
            }
        })
    }
}

func intPtrRepresentation(p *int) string {
    if p == nil {
        return "nil"
    }
    return "&" + strconv.Itoa(*p)
}
```

Comment: They are functionally equivalent because in Go everything is pass-by-value and that makes A's copy simply redundant. Also your assumption about B, namely that it *"returns the pointer to the passed value"* is not exactly accurate. The `initialVotes` argument _inside_ the function's body is a copy of the `initialVotes` variable in the caller's block.

Comment: "My question is: those two versions are not equivalent, are they?" They are equivalent. What happens exactly in machine code depends on a lot of factors but doesn't affect that these are equivalent: There is no observable difference backed by the language spec when executing these two functions. "Do I get it right, or is there more to it?" No, IMHO there is _less_ to it. "Is there a 'more idiomatic' way to do that in go?" No; such trivialities do not contribute to "idiomaticness". Especially as this is a completely unnatural, constructed excercise.

Comment: @mkopriva (and Volker) Thank you. Yes, it's pass-by-value, but if I make a copy of a pointer, it will point to the same address in memory. I think I'm carrying some assumptions from C, and I don't get it. Maybe some resources come to mind you could share?

Comment: Ah! Disregard the above. I get it now. When I pass int, the function receives a copy, so the returned value points to a new place in memory.